# Phpmyadmin will not connect 403 Forbidden

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have a mySQL server set up and it has been working perfectly, today when trying to access its data via http://www.phpmyadmin.co

I have tried on different browsers, with vpn and on different computers. Is there something wrong with phpmyadmin?

It gives the error shown below:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.
>   Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe
>
> Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) Server at www.phpmyadmin.co Port 80

If anyone knows how to fix this please let me know. Thanks

Comment: So I'm having the same error as the one you mentioned, it seems to be phpmyadmin itself as I also tried from multiple computers and a friend of mine also told me they were getting the same error.

Comment: Okay thanks Corsair. Do you know an alternative to Phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment back I'll just answer here. Yes there are a fair amount of alternatives such as Adminer and phpMiniAdmin, but it seems phpmyadmin is back online anyways.